# Plugin with id 'com.android.feature' not found

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

While converting my existing app to instant app using [this codelab tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/) encountered this error.

```
Plugin with id 'com.android.feature' not found.
```

I have checked that I have **Instant app development SDK** on Android Studio 3.0

[image]

Can someone point what i am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution:-

I have to add **google()** repository under Project's build.gradle like this

```
  allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

After which i got this error:-[image]
to solve which I had to follow first suggestion "*Upgrade plugin version to 3.0.0-beta7 and sync project*"

Next I landup upon this :-
[image]
which I followed as suggested and successfully rebuild my project :)

Happy coding!